# Does Power BI provide an OOTB Geographical Dimension Table

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

Geographical dimension tables are commonly used in a lot of data models, which has hierarchy by nature just like Date / DateTime dimensions.

I'm just wondering if there is any trick to get OOTB geographical dimension tables from Power BI, or alternatively any open source to import, so that each Power BI developer doesn't have to reinvent the wheel to create one from the scratch?